dataframe: count multiple occurrences across all columns and output dataframe with same columns, single occcurrances as indexes
I have a Pandas dataframe like this:
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'2012':['A','A','B','A'],'2013':['A','B','C','C'],'2014':['A','C','Z','C']})
>>> df

  2012 2013 2014
0    A    A    A
1    A    B    C
2    B    C    Z
3    A    C    C

From it, I need to create another dataframe like this:
   2012  2013  2014
A     3     1     1
B     1     1     0
C     0     2     2

where I am basically counting some (A,B,C but not Z) of the occurrences of the labels in every column, turning them into indexes, and showing their count per year.
I did come out with a solution that involves iteration:
>>> indexes = ['A','B','C']
>>> for idx in indexes:
        df2.loc[idx] = (df == idx).sum()
>>> df2

   2012  2013  2014
A     3     1     1
B     1     1     0
C     0     2     2

This outputs exactly what I need. But I wonder, is there a way to do it in one shot without iteration?
I played around with values_counts(), pivot_table() and groupby() without success.
All Google searches I found point to this type of count but across one column only.
Thanks in advance to whoever may help!

This will give you the count for all letters A, B, C and Z:
df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0).T

   2012  2013  2014
A     3     1     1
B     1     1     0
C     0     2     2
Z     0     0     1

You can then select the rows you want to keep:
df.loc[["A", "B", "C"]]

   2012  2013  2014
A     3     1     1
B     1     1     0
C     0     2     2


similair method using melt pd.melt(df,var_name='years').groupby(['value','years']).size().unstack(level=1,fill_value=0)

One option to avoid the stack/unstack approach is to call value_counts on each column, concatenate and process your final result:
out = {name:ser.value_counts() 
       for name, ser 
       in df.items()}
(pd
.concat(out, axis=1)
.loc['A':'C']
.fillna(0)
.astype(int)
)

   2012  2013  2014
A     3     1     1
B     1     1     0
C     0     2     2

If the data size is large, this gives you better performance.

You already have your answer, but you can also try
new_df = df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).fillna(0)

You can use one of these two lines to remove the 'Z' from the index.
new_df.loc[:'C']
new_df.loc[new_df.sum(axis=1) > 1]

End result:
    2012    2013    2014
A      3       1       1
B      1       1       0
C      0       2       2
Z      0       0       1

